# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException with Tuple key

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary keyed by a `Tuple` like this:

```
private readonly IDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, List<Bom>> bomCache
            = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, List<Bom>>();
```

I used it as a cache for a method:

```
        private async Task<List<Bom>> buildActiveBoms(string materialId, string plantId) {
            var key = new Tuple<string, string>(materialId, plantId);
            if (!bomCache.ContainsKey(key)) {
                try {
                    bomCache[key] = await loadList($"Bom:{materialId}:{plantId}", document => new Bom {
                        BomStatusId = document["BomStatusId"],
                        BomTypeId = document["BomTypeId"]
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception error) {
                    logger.Error(error);
                    throw;
                }
            }

            // how, after above condition, this entry can still not exist?
            try {
                return bomCache.ContainsKey(key) ? bomCache[key] : new List<Bom>();
            }
            catch (Exception error) {
                logger.Error(error);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

`loadList()` always returns at least empty list, but even to ensure this is handled, after adding conditional return (checking `ContainsKey()`) I still got `KeyNotFoundException:

[image: debug session]

What can be the reason of that and how to mitigate that?

Comment: "how, after above condition, this entry can still not exist?" after a race condition in a multithreaded environment

Comment: How many threads do you have in your application?

Comment: If I don't, intentionally, use multiple threads, only `async`, does this spawn threads or just run single thread asynchronously? I'm new to C# I must say and probably too naive Node-based approach?